# Play a sound with javascript in background

Tags: javascript, html, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Playing sound with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402859/playing-sound-with-javascript)

I'm making a javascript chat for my site and I need to play a sound when it has a new message and the chat is not focused, just like the Facebook's chat. Problem is I have no clue how to play this sound in background with javascript. Could you help me?

Edit: Crossbrowser solutions without Flash will be better

Comment: There are many ways to do this. If modern browsers are your only target, I'd probably go with the `audio` tag, which can be completely scripted/done from JS.

Comment: Is it possible to use this tag without the browser rendering a player?

Comment: @RodrigoWaltenberg: You can probably just hide it, or make it render outside the viewport.

Comment: @Quentin that's a great solution. I'll work on that. Sorry for the duplication, that article didn't show up on StackOverflow's sugestions when I typed my question.

Comment: @RodrigoWaltenberg Yes, you can use audio tags without any visible indication they are there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** and it's `append` function along with script;

Create an element (example - `<div>`) or use an existing element, and give it some id (like `<div id="some_div">`). Then try the below code

```
$('#some_div').append('<embed id="embed_player" src="your_sound_file.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true"></embed>');
```

Hope this helps... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

A [quick search of relevant tutorials](http://google.com/search?q=html5+audio+tutorial) should get you on your way. If you encounter any problems, feel free to ask about those specific issues rather than a broad subject.

---

> Is it possible to use this tag without the browser rendering a player?

Yes it is. Just don't add the `controls` attribute. That's what makes it show up, so if you leave it out the player won't be there.