# How to play sound when the current time equals to specific time

Tags: javascript, html

In my web page, I would like to play sound when the current time equals to , for example, 5:00 pm.

What I did is:

```
<script type='text/css'>
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var h = d.getHours();
if (h == 17 && m == 00){
document.write = "<embed src =\'notify.mp3\' hidden=\'true\' autostart=\'true\' loop=\'true\'></embed>";
}
</script>
```

I looked for a specific function that plays the sound and I found `document.write` which doesn't work and doesn't make sense.

Any suggestion what I should do

Comment: I think you should first read something like that http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8489710/how-can-i-play-sound-in-jquery-when-click-a-button

Will be useful for you...... \


http://jsbin.com/ilijif/2 this is for click to play the sound you can go for the same thing on time matching

Comment: You will need to check repeatedly if the current time is the time to play the music. Use setInterval to check the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in JS:

```
 <script>
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var h = d.getHours();
if (h == 17 && m == 00){
      var sound = document.getElementById(sound1);
      sound.Play();
}
</script>
```

Dont forget to add this in HTML

```
<embed src="notify.mp3" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="sound1"
enablejavascript="true">
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38571639/2218697)  plays sounds if **browser is inactive or minimized** by the user.  Hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

**Try something like this.**

```
document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML= "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
```

**Using The  Element**

The  tag defines a container for external (non-HTML) content. The following code fragment should play an MP3 file embedded in a web page:

Example

```
<embed height="50" width="100" src="horse.mp3">
```

**Or try**

Try using this revised version of the function play()

```
function play() 
{
  var embed=document.createElement('object');
  embed.setAttribute('type','audio/wav');
  embed.setAttribute('data', 'c:\test.wav');
  embed.setAttribute('autostart', true);
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(embed);
}
```

Refence: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

http://webdesign.about.com/od/sound/a/play_sound_oncl.htm

[Playing sound with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402859/playing-sound-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to create an alarm-like functionality. Here's what I would do:

```
var delay = 60000; // in milliseconds, check every minute
var intervalId = setInterval("playWhenReady()", delay);

function playWhenReady()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes(); 

    if (h === 17 && m === 00)
    {
        playSound('notify.mp3');
        clearInterval(intervalId);              
    }
}

function playSound(soundFile)
{
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', soundFile);
    audioElement.play();
}
```