# How to play a music at a timepoint javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I've seen this: [How to play sound when the current time equals to specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209628/how-to-play-sound-when-the-current-time-equals-to-specific-time) But i can't use the object in the html in my situation. I just have the path of my music in a service.

And I don't know why but I can't set my music at a current time when I have to continu.

```
audioObj = new Audio()

play(music: Music): void {
  this.audioObj.src = this.baseUrl + music.fileUrl
  this.audioObj.load()
}
```

And this is in my constructor :

```
    this.audioObj.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', (audio:any) => {
      this.audioObj.currentTime = 50 // just for my test
      this.audioObj.play() // but my music start over at 0
    })
```

Thank you so much if you have the solution :)

Comment: Do you want to play music at a specific time based on the browser time or do you want to play audio starting at a specific spot in the audio file?

Comment: thank you for your response, just at a specific spot in the audio file

Comment: `.load()` is not a synchronous operation. if you want to "start playing at some time", explicitly do that in response to load finishing.

Comment: thank you @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. But what is the best way do to that ?

Comment: Same way you listen for anything else in the DOM spec: add an event listener for [whichever load event is the most appropriate for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#Events).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did an update, thanks again